# How can I fix broken image thumbnails in the Google Picker DocsView List mode without using a restricted scope?

Tags: google-picker

I want to use the Google Picker API to create a Google Drive file picker for a web app I'm working on. The problem I'm running into is that in the `DocsView` list mode, images are displayed with broken thumbnails:

[image]

I'm using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope, which is the scope recommended in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs#display-the-google-picker). If I use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` scope instead, the thumbnails work fine. However, this has several drawbacks:

1. The `drive.readonly` scope is restricted, which [requires](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth?hl=en#assessment) the app to go through restricted scope verification and a security assessment.
2. This scope has more permissions than the app requires, and more than the end user may want to grant ("See and download all your Google Drive files" is the language in the OAuth consent screen.)

In my opinion the correct behavior when using the recommended `drive.file` scope should be to display the generic image icon (like this: [image: generic image icon]) rather than make use of thumbnail URLs that are guaranteed to return 403 errors and thus the browser's broken image icon, which is not a great look.

Is there a workaround? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** There's some question as to whether the `drive.readonly` scope is restricted. I'm pretty sure [it is](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth?hl=en#OAuth2Authorizing):
[image: screenshot of scopes documentation]

**UPDATE 2:** It looks like the documentation is wrong -- in GCP it's listed as a sensitive scope in the OAuth app registration. See comment by @ziganotschka below. Also, I've created a new [tracker issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208855070).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two things:

1. As per [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#sensitive-scopes&zippy=%2Cgmail-apis), only the following scopes are restricted:

> https://mail.google.com/ (includes any usage of IMAP, SMTP, and POP3 protocols)
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is not on the list, and thus - not restricted, but only sensitive.

- You can verify this by [adding the scopes to the Outh screen](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuser-consent%2Cpublic-and-internal-applications%2Cauthorized-domains):

  Go to your GCP console -> "APIs & Services" -> "OAuth Consent Screen" -> "Prepare for verification" -> "Scopes" -> "Add or remove scopes" -> Paste `googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` -> "Add to table" -> "Update". You will see that the scope will be added to the list "Your sensitive scopes", not "Your restricted scopes".

- Thus, you do not need to go through restricted scope verification if you want to use this scope. You will only be prompted to explain why you need this scope and show screencast of your App, where it is shown for what you use this scope in your app.

2. The issue with the 403 error and broken thumbnails is well known and multiply reported on [Google Issue's Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/63268306). However, it looks like it is [intended behaviour](https://issuetracker.google.com/179397319).

So the only workaround would be to go ahead and use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` scope - do not worry about problems with verification.

Comment: Thanks for finding the tracker issue! However, I do think it's a restricted scope. I updated my question to show a screenshot where the documentation lists the scope as **restricted**

Comment: Hi David! This is outdated information, go onto your GCP console -> "APIs & Services" -> "OAuth Consent Screen" -> "Prepare for verification" -> "Scopes" -> "Add or remove scopes" -> Paste "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" -> "Add to table" -> "Update".  You will see that the scope will be added to the list "Your sensitive scopes", not "Your restricted scopes", so you will not have any problems with verification.

Comment: Thanks! You're correct. I've submitted feedback to update the documentation. I've also created a new issue (which I've linked to in the question), because I do think the current behavior with the drive.file scope is broken. I don't want the drive.readonly scope -- I just want to the picker to display a generic image icon when I'm using my desired (and recommended) scope.

Comment: Makes sense! For the mean time, I will update my answer to included the contents of the comments and avoid confusion in case other users stumble upon the same issue.